# Middle date from Two date fields

Tags: apex, datetime, date

I have a Requirement where there are Two dates field (Delivery Date) and another field is (Delivery Date of Remaining Material) , I want to half value of date for eg Delivery date is 10/May/2021 and Delivery Date of Remaining Material is 30/May/2021, I want the output to be like 20/May/2021. Middle date from both dates in APEX class.
Kindly please Help

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This site isn't a free coding service, so the expectation is that you have made an attempt to do this yourself and will share that attempt with us. This site thrives on details and people being able to point to a very narrow and specific issue. You can [edit] your question to add those things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Half date from Two date fields store in date field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343126/half-date-from-two-date-fields-store-in-date-field)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by averaging the milliseconds from both dates, and recreating a new DateTime from it. Here's a simple method:

```
public static Date midDate(Date date1, Date date2) {
    Time midnight = Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return DateTime.newInstance(
        (
            DateTime.newInstance(date1, midnight).getTime()+
            DateTime.newInstance(date2, midnight).getTime()
        )/2
    ).date();
}
```

Which you'd use as:

```
Date date1 = Date.newInstance(2021,5,10);
Date date2 = Date.newInstance(2021,5,30);
Date halfWayDate = midDate(date1,date2);
```